# Generic Sensor API in Web Worker

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, web-worker

I'm working on a **Progressive Web App** with **Ionic 4**.
I'm able to use **Generic Sensor API** in the main thread, but I want to use it in a **Web Worker**, to read device motions (accelerometer, gyroscope, ...) with an event listener in **background**, when the app is not active (but opened in background).

Is there a way to do that ? Or is it an actual **limitation of PWAs** ?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? curious

Comment: I didn't, I don't know if it's still impossible now.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to access a Sensor API from Web Workers.

This is because Web Workers can not interact with the user and some API might ask for the user's permissions.

Workers are limited to a small subset of APIs which can be found at MDN: [Functions and classes available to workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers#web_apis_available_in_workers)

Some of them include the

- messaging APIs
- limited Navigator API
- fetch API, XMLHttpRequest and WebSockets
- Data storage
- ...

See also: [Web Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#functions_and_interfaces_available_in_workers)

However, what you can do is, listening to for sensor data in the main thread and [sending it via the messaging APIs to the Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#sending_messages_to_and_from_a_dedicated_worker).